# Installation nolearn issue

Tags: python-2.7, installation, neural-network, theano

I want to use nolearn but I am not able to install it. I can' t use pip installation so I tried as in the figure. Any idea how can I solve this? Thank you
[image]

Comment: Looks like you couldn't connect to `python.org`. Did you test your network connection? Try to run `$ pip search tabulate` - does it return with an error?

Comment: yes it is a connection problem,it return something like connection error (Timeout)! How can I solve it?

Comment: Then it is not the installation process that falters. Make sure that you aren't blocking network connections from cmd in your firewall. You could try to run `$ ping www.stackoverflow.com` to see if the cmd prompt is allowed to reach the Internet.

Comment: You should be able to view this web page in a browser: `https://pypi.python.org/` (note it's https, not http). If you can't then there is a network/firewall/proxy issue. If you can then try the install again.

Comment: I can see this webpage so I will try again. I' ll let you know

Comment: I ran ping www.stackoverflow.com and it worked but I can't still install nolearn